# Read string to a formatted way using regex and c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I am capturing mainframe screen using c# and I have to read the labels corresponds to for the text entering region from the screen. Currently Iam reading it from the captured image using **tesseract ocr** plugin, It returns a string, I want split that string according to some characters in it. The characters are the following.

```
{ '@', '<', '>', '=', '$', '%', '&' }
```

and for splitting a sample string is shown below

```
first name => saran    address @> my address
```

Any way to split this string using regex as the following format to an array

```
[0]: "first name"
[1]: "=> saran" 
[2]: "address" 
[3]: "@> my address"
```

Comment: So you want to split by "=>" and "@>"?

Comment: @john  No. It may be any character from { '@', '<', '>', '=', '$', '%', '&' }

Comment: What if the name or address contains one of those characters?

Comment: @john I am reading the text from some images using OCR, actually its a good question, I think I have to validate maximum possible scenarios in this case, I think that only I can do in this case.

Comment: `saran    address`, How is this split?

Comment: you might want to break down the problem into seperate ones as you are splitting not only by the specified characters but also by shitespaces between `saran` and `address`

Comment: You'll need a _real_ predictable pattern before you can split this stuff. Please give better examples.

Answer (score 1):

This gets you very close (but not using `Regex`):

```
char[] splitters = new[] { '@', '<', '>', '=', '$', '%', '&' };

string text = "first name => saran    address @> my address";

string[] results =
    text
        .Aggregate(new List<List<char>>() { new List<char>() }, (a, c) =>
        {
            var l = a.Last();
            if (splitters.Contains(c) && !l.All(x => splitters.Contains(x)))
            {
                l = new List<char>() { c };
                a.Add(l);
            }
            else
            {
                l.Add(c);
            }
            return a;
        })
        .Select(x => new string(x.ToArray()))
        .ToArray();
```

There's just nothing in your description as to how to split `"saran    address"`. Other than that this is tested and produces this:

```
first name  
=> saran    address  
@> my address
```

Comment: Fancy linq, but you realize just String.Split with the RemoveEmptyEntries option gives exactly the same result, right?

Comment: @Nyerguds - No, it doesn't. The OP wants to retain the splitting characters. It's also not splitting on consecutive splitting characters.

Comment: Ah, point. Thought the consecutive splitting itself doesn't matter much with the `.Split` method. OP never indicated if these symbols have any meaning though, and never explicitly confirmed they need to be preserved. His own split example is dodgy, with index 1 shown as `[1]: => "saran"` with the `=>` not even inside the quotes.

Comment: @Enigmativity. Thank you, actually Im reading this strings from image, Its returning strings like "saran    address". I want to make it formatted and to write it on a file. Actually I have the  same doubt about splitting "saran    address". I think I can find out a solution for that also.